# Regarding GitHub and version control

Tags: github

Recently, we have started a group project and decided to use GitHub to share the code among ourselves.
For example, if I created a login page and my friend created a home page, how can I get it on my local machine.
I mean, whenever a change is made to the repo, do we need to download it all again?

Comment: Run `git pull` to get the latest changes

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of GitHub is that you can always go back whenever you feel like.

Whenever a changed is made by any of the teammate, it's a really good practice that you `push` that change. Even when it's a small one. After you've *pushed* your changes, your teammates would need to `pull` that change.

The best sequence for this is;

```
- git commit
- git pull
- git push
```

You'll have to pull the changes first as it would help you avoid getting `merge conflicts.` If you get any merge conflicts on any line, or any function, you'll resolve that conflict and follow the same sequence once again.

So, to conclude, GitHub is so easy to use and you won't have to necessary **'Download'** all the changes once again. I would recommend you to setup via *Visual Studio 2019* so that it becomes easier for you to just "pull" the changes whenever a new change has been made.